# Is Cubert Farnsworth a failed project?

Tags: futurama

Hubert Farnsworth cloned himself a clone to finish his accomplishments and to become his legacy after he passes away.  That resulted in the creation of Cubert.  The purpose of Cubert was to finish the inventions of Hubert Farnsworth.

However, the show, has there been any indication that Cubert finished any of Professor Farnsworth's inventions?  If not, wouldn't that make Cubert a failed project, since he doesn't do what he was cloned for?

The show did indicate that Cubert called himself a failed experiment, but that was before Cubert decided to become a scientist like the Professor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Cubert](http://theinfosphere.org/Cubert_J._Farnsworth) is still a kid, at least biologically. Chronologically, he is 23, just like his youthful friend [Dwight Conrad](http://theinfosphere.org/Dwight_Conrad). This suggests that humans may age slower since they live longer in the future.

Nevertheless, Cubert is still in school, so there's no reason to think he can immediately pick up on all the unfinished projects the Professor has. He has already shown some scientific prowess, like when he repairs the Planet Express ship's engine in ["A Clone of My Own"](http://theinfosphere.org/A_Clone_of_My_Own), but he likely needs more schooling before he can fully take the Professor's place.

Comment: I wouldn't agree with the *aging*. Like in *The Simpsons*, people inside the Universe do not appear to age from Season to Season, while the In-Universe date does seem to progress. Wibbly-wobbly timey-wimey stuff.

Comment: @bitmask: Except that some characters do appear to age, or at least their aging is specifically pointed out, like with the Professor. The fact that there's no aging for *some* characters is likely a convenient inconsistency for the writers, but I was just trying to give it some in-universe justification.